# Is there a way to enter text into a website with python?

Tags: python

Basically, I need to make a python program that can go to a website and enter text. 
For example, going to google and entering text into the search box and then pressing enter.
 Is that even possible?

Comment: `urllib` can do this.  If you don't see how, that means you are thinking about the problem the wrong way.

Comment: Visually, [selenium](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) can do this, but that may be taking things a bit far for a simple task.

Answer (score 2):

Zack is correct, `urllib` can do the job. The problem is there is no generic way on how websites accept input.

Ex:
Google Search:

'http://www.google.com/search?q=looking+for+something'

Yahoo Search:
'http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=looking+for+something'

check this [howto](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/urllib2.html) to know more about urllib